# How to attach DLL file in maven based project

Tags: java, windows, maven, dll

Can you tell me how to in elegant way attach `dll` file to my project based on maven ?

When I put into system32 id does work (of course due to that system32 belongs to `PATH`).  However, my aim is to make app more portable (of course among windows based OSes)
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about having the dll in Resource folders then copy and perform the operations in runtime.  Like below code.

```
 package dllportable;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URISyntaxException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.nio.file.Files;

    public class dllportable {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
            URL url=dllportable.class.getClassLoader().getResource("config.dll");
            System.out.println(url.toURI());
            Files.copy(new File(url.toURI()).toPath(), new File("C:\\haroon\\config.dll").toPath());
// Then your Operations on the DLL
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why this is downvoted?. user mentioned about attaching the dll and not about using DLL in maven project. If about using dll, could have suggested JNI

Comment: Lets suggest this JNI, then I accept your post. I dont know what does it mean JNI, but effect should be that app is portable.

Comment: JNI is Java Native Interface. when we have some libraries in java and some in different technology (like .Net or C++) JNI is used to bridge those gaps. I used Com4J https://github.com/kohsuke/com4j in the past to build a bridge. Your portable application is in VB.NET If I'm right. I wish to see better details on how to proceed. either as JNI or leave as it   is as dll. Because it includes time investment.

Comment: Also for VB.net, we can just have exe to run in windows if we don't have any specific dll created for that specific exe you have. as an FYI...

Comment: My problem looks: In logs I got error: Coulnt find dll: someLibrary.dll
When I put this into some PATH directory (eg system32) it does work. However, I would like to get universal solution, no copy

Comment: Either it is windows standard dll OR App developer created dll. we need to have that copied for exe to run. Even famous vb.net programs error out saying system dll is missing. In such case we download and copy dll s. May I know why you are so much against copy :)

Comment: I would like be able push project into repo and my collegues only pull and run (dont think about copying)

Comment: With this code Pull and run will work. DLL will be stay Resources folder. Thank you!